# How to get this jquery plugin to work without an element

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm just having my first foray into writing jquery plugins. I've downloaded a "boilerplate" and I'm just experimenting with it to get my head around it.

The boilerplate code (taken from http://jqueryboilerplate.com/) is here:

```
// the semi-colon before function invocation is a safety net against concatenated
// scripts and/or other plugins which may not be closed properly.
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

        // undefined is used here as the undefined global variable in ECMAScript 3 is
        // mutable (ie. it can be changed by someone else). undefined isn't really being
        // passed in so we can ensure the value of it is truly undefined. In ES5, undefined
        // can no longer be modified.

        // window and document are passed through as local variable rather than global
        // as this (slightly) quickens the resolution process and can be more efficiently
        // minified (especially when both are regularly referenced in your plugin).

        // Create the defaults once
        var pluginName = "defaultPluginName",
                defaults = {
                propertyName: "value"
        };

        // The actual plugin constructor
        function Plugin ( element, options ) {
                this.element = element;
                // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or
                // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
                // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
                // future instances of the plugin
                this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
                this._defaults = defaults;
                this._name = pluginName;
                this.init();
        }

        // Avoid Plugin.prototype conflicts
        $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
                init: function () {
                        // Place initialization logic here
                        // You already have access to the DOM element and
                        // the options via the instance, e.g. this.element
                        // and this.settings
                        // you can add more functions like the one below and
                        // call them like so: this.yourOtherFunction(this.element, this.settings).
                        console.log("xD");
                        this.yourOtherFunction();
                },
                yourOtherFunction: function () {
                        // some logic
                        alert("in other function");
                }
        });

        // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
        // preventing against multiple instantiations
        $.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
                this.each(function() {
                        if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                                $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
                        }
                });

                // chain jQuery functions
                return this;
        };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

I have put in two calls to the plugin like so:

```
$(".form_result_message").defaultPluginName({
          propertyName: "a custom value"
        });
```

The top one works... this next one gives me an error `"TypeError: $.defaultPluginName is not a function"`....

```
var testingThis = $.defaultPluginName({
          propertyName: "a custom value"
        });
```

Could someone explain to me why this isn't working and how I must call it to get it to work without attaching it to an element?

Many thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you define a plugin as `$.fn[pluginName]`, that makes it a method on jQuery objects. If you want it to be an ordinary function rather than a method, you should define `$[pluginName]`:

```
$[pluginName] = function (options) {
    ...
};
```

However, this doesn't make sense for a plugin that does `this.each(...)` -- if you don't apply it to any elements, what do you expect `this` to refer to?

Comment: Ahhhh... that makes perfect sense. Many thanks for the explaination. I'll accept your answer (just got to wait 8 minutes for some reason?) Thanks again.